# Changing the first letter of a string into upper case in python

Tags: python, string

I aim to convert a proper noun for instance to have an upper case first letter after an input of the name has been made.

Comment: So, what's your question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `string.title()` you achieve that:

```
>>> name = 'joe'
>>> name.title()
'Joe'
```

Comment: Is this for python 3

Comment: 've tested that on `repl.it` Python 3.6 compiler; it works. `'joe'.title(); 'Joe'`

Comment: Does not work for `joe is nice`! Converts to `Joe Is Nice`. Look at gsamaras answer which is correct.

Comment: @Abdullah you would need to assign the value to **name** like #gsamaras did, otherwise it wont change it.

Answer (score 10):

Use [`upper()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_upper.htm) method, like this:

```
mystr = "hello world"
mystr = mystr[0].upper() + mystr[1:]
```

Comment: yes, good approach, but never use str as a variable name, that will cause pain for your future self

Comment: @gordonwrigley I agree, updated, but if you have a better suggestion, please let me know. Thank you for that!

Answer (score 3):

.capitalize() and .title(), can be used, but both have issues:

```
>>> "onE".capitalize()
'One'
>>> "onE".title()
'One'
```

Both changes other letters of the string to smallcase.
Write your own:

```
>>> xzy = lambda x: x[0].upper() + x[1:]
>>> xzy('onE')
'OnE'
```

Comment: Proper examples: "hello world".title() == 'Hello World',  "hello world".capitalize() == 'Hello world'

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://pydash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pydash.strings.capitalize.

Install `pydash` - `pip install pydash`

example:

```py
from pydash import py_

greetings = "hello Abdullah"

py_.capitalize(greetings)                  # returns 'Hello abdullah'
py_.capitalize(greetings, strict = False)  # returns 'Hello Abdullah'
```